# Dynamically scrape JSON values

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanted to scrape some data from a JSON response. Here is the [link](https://www.cbr.nl/web/show?id=289168&langid=43&channel=json&cachetimeout=-1&elementHolder=289170&ssiObjectClassName=nl.gx.webmanager.cms.layout.PagePart&ssiObjectId=285674&contentid=3780&examtype=B)

I need the values in `lessonTypes`. I want to export all the values separated with a comma.
So `Theorieopleidingen` has 4 values `Beroepsopleidingen` has 8 and so on.

[image]

I want to dynamically scrape so even if the num of values is changing, it always scrapes all with comma seperated.

Sorry if my explanation is week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a JSON object, why don't you use just `requests` and do what(ever) you want (with the data).

For example:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.cbr.nl/web/show?id=289168&langid=43&channel=json&cachetimeout=-1&elementHolder=289170&ssiObjectClassName=nl.gx.webmanager.cms.layout.PagePart&ssiObjectId=285674&contentid=3780&examtype=B"
for value in requests.get(url).json()['lessonTypes'].values():
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
['Motor', 'Auto', 'Bromfiets', 'Tractor']
['Bus', 'Aanhangwagen achter bus', 'Vrachtauto', 'Aanhangwagen achter vrachtauto', 'Heftruck', 'ADR', 'Taxi', 'Tractor']
['Aangepaste auto', 'Automaat personenauto']
['Motor', 'Auto', 'Aanhangwagen achter auto', 'Bromfiets', 'Brommobiel']
```

EDIT:

To access individual keys and their values you might want to try this for example:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.cbr.nl/web/show?id=289168&langid=43&channel=json&cachetimeout=-1&elementHolder=289170&ssiObjectClassName=nl.gx.webmanager.cms.layout.PagePart&ssiObjectId=285674&contentid=3780&examtype=B"
lesson_types = requests.get(url).json()['lessonTypes']
print(list(lesson_types.keys()))
print("\n".join(lesson_types['Theorieopleidingen']))
```

Output:

```
['Theorieopleidingen', 'Beroepsopleidingen', 'Bijzonderheden', 'Praktijkopleidingen']
Motor
Auto
Bromfiets
Tractor
```

Comment: I was doing this with Scrapy and JSON library.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that but you already get a JSON as a response, so why not simplify?

Comment: Those four line solutions...

Comment: Scrapy is good when you need to get data from certain parts of a website (i.e. go through HTML), but if the site already returns raw data, there's no point of using it, and so this is a better solution.

Comment: I didn't use requests before so I have to use scrapy now.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I target each element in lessonTypes? I tried your way and it worked but when I do it like this:

for value in schools['lessonTypes']['Theorieopleidingen'].values() it gives me an error.

Comment: It gives you an error because `Theorieopleidingen` is a list, not a dict. I'll update my answer.